# How to make webform forget a selected event?

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-views

[image]I'm using Views to display some events, the user clicks on one and that fires up a webform where they can sign up for the chosen event (so passing the event id in the url).  All working well but...if the user then selects a different event in the webform (not unreasonable) then that event becomes the default event - and won't go away.  Even when the user later selects a different event in Views, when they come to the webform the previously chosen event will be selected - not the one they selected and was passed in the url.  This feels like a bug, and should be easy to reproduce, but maybe there's an explanation or way of stopping this? (Upgraded to latest 5.3.1 still same problem). First screenshot is Views & you can see the url correctly generated for event id 19.  Second screen shows event on Aug 4 incorrectly selected which is event id 18 (I selected this at a previous time)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful when sending people to a webform that has multiple events on them. If they return to that webform (or another webform that pulls in the same Events) at a later time and select another event -> what they are technically doing is canceling their participant registration for the event they un-select and registering themselves for the newly select event.

The setting to not unregister participants from Events will just affect the processing of the form; On load of the webform it does makes sense to me that it shows the Event one is current registered for.

Comment: True, and I fixed that by checking 'Disable unregistering participants from unselected events'.  I unchecked that, but still the problem persists.

Comment: Can you get us some screenshots? Then I'll try and reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: We had this issue once but turning off the setting of "unregistered participants from unselected events" resolved it for us